# Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

i have a RestController with the below Post code and try to use it in my AJAX to add data in the Database Table. i habe the below Error.

RestController methode Post

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@RequestBody MessageChat chatmessage) {
        messageService.save(chatmessage);

    }
```

Ajax call

```
$( "#vut" ).on( "click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $.ajax({
               url: '/messagechat',
               method: 'POST',ContentType:'application/json',dataType: 'JSON',
               data: {
                      message: 'a'
                  }
                })

    });
```

Error

```
{"timestamp":1498660502132,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/messagechat"}
```

Somebody can help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$( "#vut" ).on( "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
           url: '/messagechat',
           method: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: JSON.stringify({message: 'a'})
    });
});
```

And in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public void create(@RequestBody MessageChat chatmessage) {
    messageService.save(chatmessage);

}
```

Comment: thanks for answers , i have try that und have that error  message":"Content type 'application/json' not supported","path":"/messagechat"

Comment: Working fine. Thanks you :D

Answer (score 2):

Try "**c**ontentType" instead of "**C**ontentType"

Comment: thanks for answers , i have try that und have that error  message":"Content type 'application/json' not supported","path":"/messagechat"

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation of **jQuery**'s function `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you should change the name of the attribute from `ContentType` to `contentType`. Javascript identifiers are not case insensitive.

Comment: thanks for answers , i have try that und have that error  message":"Content type 'application/json' not supported","path":"/messagechat"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*)
```

Alternatively you can also set it to headers="Accept=application/json"